# Unreal Engine 4.7 cant create a normal skybox

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unreal-engine4, skybox

**Intro:** So here I am coming from the Unreal Answerhub site since that place is truly unresponsive and alot of tutorials and resources are out of date as of the latest release 4.7 which changed the workflow.

**The Problem:**

I recently switched from Unity to Unreal and the first thing I wanted to do is create a skybox but the only thing it seems to support is a skydome which has far more polygons than a cube and the generated .dds cubemap files are far too huge to be used in webgl projects. Apart from that I dont know how to set up a simple sky.

**What I Expect to Happen:**

I want to try and get a simple traditional skybox up and running which uses 6 images instead of dds files for performance sake.

**What I Tried:**

**1)** I followed every 4.6 tutorial out there but without success since 4.7 has slightly changed the way we work with blueprints. Also the interface changed so it is hard for me as a new user to follow.

**2)** I tried my own method of creating a cube in the open source program Blender. Flipped the normals of the cube and uv mapped each of the 6 faces associated with my 6 images. Exported and imported to Unreal Engine. Scaled it to be huge. The problem is, as soon as the player walks the image im facing to seem to get closer. Is there a way to prevent that from happening? Like making it infinite or making the cubes center of gravity follow the player?

*I would be really grateful for an answer. Not only will you help me but alot of others who dont get an answer from the unreal community regarding this issue.*

Sincerely,

Maros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marketplace has some cheap high-resolution space skyboxes, maybe you could have a look how they do it. Alternatively, you can procedurally generate your sky in a blueprint like in the UE4 content examples. And it does not really matter performance-wise if your skydome has 8 or 800 vertices.

Basically, the solution for a cubic skydome is what you already did with your point 2).
What scale did you use for it to be "huge"? If you make the scale big enough (something like 1000000), it will NOT move once you move your player.

Comment: Like 500 or so. Cant remember just big enough so it looks good. Doesnt an overdimensional scale of 100000 or so make my skybox look tiny or lets say too far away? Ill have to test that. Thing is I got some planets which I believe would look too small when scaled too much since the faces get further away from the player

Comment: if your player is in the middle of the cube then additional scaling does not affect what you see. Same for the planets - if you scale them up and move them away proportionally, the player is not able to tell the difference while standing. The only difference is that a large scaled object does not seem to move relative to the player, so it looks like it is part of the background.

Comment: Ok it seems to work. One question though, why is it that they removed the old way of doing skyboxes? I mean what is the advantage over a skydome? dds files are over hundred mb huge where 6 optimized high definition jpg are 10 times lower.

Comment: I really do not know, I asked myself that question. Maybe they want to push developers more to their blueprint-based dynamic sky solution, but that is just an overkill for many smaller games.